# Changing a node in a tree in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a function that, given a tree structure, returns a copy of that tree but with a node changed at a particular index. Here is what I have so far:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Node {
    Value(u32),
    Branch(u32, Box<Node>, Box<Node>),
}

fn main() {
    let root = Node::Branch(1, Box::new(Node::Value(2)), Box::new(Node::Value(3)));
    zero_node(&root, 2);
}

pub fn zero_node (tree: &Node, node_index: u8) -> Node {

    let mut new_tree = tree.clone();

    fn zero_rec (node : &mut Node, node_count : u8, node_index : u8) -> u8 {
        if (node_index == node_count) {
            match node {
                &mut Node::Value(_) => { *node = Node::Value(0); },
                &mut Node::Branch(_, ref mut left, ref mut right) => { *node = Node::Branch(0, *left, *right);  }
            }
            node_count
        } else {
            match node {
                &mut Node::Value(val) => {1},
                &mut Node::Branch(_, ref mut left, ref mut right) => {
                    let count_left = zero_rec(&**left, node_count + 1, node_index);
                    let count_right = zero_rec(&**right, node_count + 1 + count_left, node_index);
                    count_left + count_right + 1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    zero_rec(&new_tree, 0, node_index);

    new_tree

}
```

http://is.gd/YdIm0g

I can't seem to work my way out of errors like: "cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable" and "cannot move out of borrowed content".

I could create the new tree from scratch based on the original, and alter one node in the process. But I'd like to understand how to win this fight with the borrow checker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code compiles:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Node {
    Value(u32),
    Branch(u32, Box<Node>, Box<Node>),
}

fn main() {
    let root = Node::Branch(1, Box::new(Node::Value(2)), Box::new(Node::Value(3)));
    zero_node(&root, 2);
}

pub fn zero_node (tree: &Node, node_index: u8) -> Node {

    let mut new_tree = tree.clone();

    fn zero_rec (node : &mut Node, node_count : u8, node_index : u8) -> u8 {
        if node_index == node_count {
            match node {
                &mut Node::Value(ref mut val) => { *val = 0; },
                &mut Node::Branch(ref mut val, _, _) => { *val = 0; }
            }
            node_count
        } else {
            match node {
                &mut Node::Value(_) => {1},
                &mut Node::Branch(_, ref mut left, ref mut right) => {
                    let count_left = zero_rec(&mut **left, node_count + 1, node_index);
                    let count_right = zero_rec(&mut **right, node_count + 1 + count_left, node_index);
                    count_left + count_right + 1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    zero_rec(&mut new_tree, 0, node_index);

    new_tree

}
```

The changes I made were:

- `&new_tree` → `&mut new_tree` and `&**left` → `&mut **left` etc.: the way to create an `&mut T` reference is with the `&mut` operator (i.e. the `mut` is necessary). This fixes the `cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable` error by passing a mutable reference rather than an immutable
- changing the `node_index == node_count` branch to directly mutate the values, rather than trying to overwrite in place. This fixes the `cannot move out of borrowed content` error by just not doing any moves at all.

The overwriting could actually be achieved with careful use of `std::mem::replace`, to swap in a new value (e.g. `Value(0)` since that's cheap to create) to the `left` and `right` references. The `replace` functions returns the value that existed before, i.e. exactly the things inside `left` and `right` that you need to create the new branch. This change to the relevant `match` arm looks a bit like:

```
&mut Node::Branch(_, ref mut left, ref mut right) => { 
    let l = mem::replace(left, Box::new(Node::Value(0)));
    let r = mem::replace(right, Box::new(Node::Value(0)));
    *node = Node::Branch(0, l , r); 
}
```

(Having added `use std::mem;` to the top of the file.)

However it hits a new error:

```
<anon>:25:9: 25:39 error: cannot assign to `*node` because it is borrowed
<anon>:25                   *node = Node::Branch(0, l , r); 
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:22:26: 22:38 note: borrow of `*node` occurs here
<anon>:22               &mut Node::Branch(_, ref mut left, ref mut right) => { 
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The `left` and `right` values are pointers deep into the old contents of `node`, so, as far as the compiler knows (at the moment), overwriting `node` will invalidate those pointers which would cause any further code using them to be broken (of course, we can see that neither are used more, but the compiler doesn't pay attention to things like that yet). Fortunately there's an easy fix: both `match` arms are setting `node` to a new value, so we can use the `match` to compute the new value and then set `node` to it after doing the computation:

```
*node = match node {
    &mut Node::Value(_) => Node::Value(0),
    &mut Node::Branch(_, ref mut left, ref mut right) => { 
        let l = mem::replace(left, Box::new(Node::Value(0)));
        let r = mem::replace(right, Box::new(Node::Value(0)));
        Node::Branch(0, l , r)
    }
};
```

(NB. the order of operations is a little strange, that's the same as `let new_val = match node { ... }; *node = new_val;`.)

*However*, that is more expensive than doing it as I wrote above, since it has to allocate 2 new boxes for the new `Branch`, while the one that modifies in-place doesn't have to do this.

---

A slightly "nicer" version might be (comments inline):

```
#[derive(Clone, Show)]
pub enum Node {
    Value(u32),
    Branch(u32, Box<Node>, Box<Node>),
}

fn main() {
    let root = Node::Branch(1, Box::new(Node::Value(2)), Box::new(Node::Value(3)));
    let root = zero_node(root, 2);

    println!("{:?}", root);
}

// Taking `tree` by value (i.e. not by reference, &) possibly saves on
// `clone`s: the user of `zero_node can transfer ownership (with no
// deep cloning) if they no longer need their tree.
//
// Alternatively, it is more flexible for the caller if it takes 
// `&mut Node` and returns () as it avoids them having to be careful 
// to avoid moving out of borrowed data.
pub fn zero_node (mut tree: Node, node_index: u8) -> Node {

    fn zero_rec (node : &mut Node, node_count : u8, node_index : u8) -> u8 {
        if node_index == node_count {
            // dereferencing once avoids having to repeat &mut a lot
            match *node {
                // it is legal to match on multiple patterns, if they bind the same
                // names with the same types
                Node::Value(ref mut val) | 
                    Node::Branch(ref mut val, _, _) => { *val = 0; },
            }
            node_count
        } else {
            match *node {
                Node::Value(_) => 1,
                Node::Branch(_, ref mut left, ref mut right) => {
                    let count_left = zero_rec(&mut **left, node_count + 1, node_index);
                    let count_right = zero_rec(&mut **right, node_count + 1 + count_left, node_index);
                    count_left + count_right + 1
                }
            }
        }
    }

    zero_rec(&mut tree, 0, node_index);

    tree

}
```