# How to set raw headers in Hyper at runtime?

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm trying to set headers on a Hyper `Response` at runtime.  In the real code, the headers come from a file so I don't know what they are at compile-time.  Unfortunately, I've dug through documentation and all the examples I could find but haven't seen somebody doing this.  Here's the code:

```
extern crate hyper;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io::{Read,Write};
use hyper::server::{Handler,Server,Response,Request};
use hyper::header::*;

fn main() {
    let headers = HashMap::new();
    headers.insert("X-Test-Header".to_string(), "test_value".to_string());
    let responder = Responder::new(headers);

    Server::http("127.0.0.1:1340")
    .unwrap()
    .handle(responder)
    .unwrap();
}

struct Responder {
    headers: HashMap<String, String>
}

impl Responder {
    pub fn new(headers: HashMap<String,String>) -> Self {
        Responder {
            headers: headers.clone()
        }
    }
    fn respond_success(&self, mut res: Response, content: &[u8]) {
        res.headers_mut()
            .set(ContentLength(content.len() as u64));
        for (key, val) in self.headers.iter() {
            res.headers_mut()
                .set_raw(key.as_str(), vec![val.into_bytes()])
        }
        let mut res_body = res.start().unwrap();
        res_body.write_all(content).unwrap();
    }
}

impl Handler for Responder {
    fn handle(&self, req: Request, res: Response) {
        let content = b"Hello World!";
        self.respond_success(res, content);
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\main.rs:31:40
   |
31 |         for (key, val) in self.headers.iter() {
   |                                        ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 28:65...
  --> src\main.rs:28:66
   |
28 |     fn respond_success(&self, mut res: Response, content: &[u8]) {
   |                                                                  ^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src\main.rs:31:27
   |
31 |         for (key, val) in self.headers.iter() {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that types are compatible (expected std::convert::From<&str>, found std::convert::From<&str>)
  --> src\main.rs:33:18
   |
33 |                 .set_raw(key.as_str(), vec![val.into_bytes()])
   |                  ^^^^^^^
```

It looks like `set_raw` needs something static but I'm not sure what my best option for refactoring this is.  Does `responder` have to be static?  That seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the signature for [`Headers::set_raw`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.10.10/hyper/header/struct.Headers.html#method.set_raw):

```
fn set_raw<K>(&mut self, name: K, value: Vec<Vec<u8>>)
where 
    K: Into<Cow<'static, str>>
```

This says that `name` can be any type that can be converted into a [`Cow<'static, str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html). That means that it can be either a `&'static str` *or* a `String`.

Next, review what types you are trying to pass:

```
.set_raw(key.as_str(), vec![val.into_bytes()])
```

1. [`String::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str) returns a string slice that lives as long as the `String` it's called on, which *is not* that `'static` lifetime.

   Instead, you need to get an owned string.
2. You are calling [`String::into_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes) on a `&String`, but, as described in [Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423), you cannot as it takes the receiver by value.

   Instead, you need to get an owned copy of the bytes.

Together, it looks like:

```
for (key, val) in self.headers.iter() {
    res.headers_mut()
        .set_raw(key.clone(), vec![val.clone().into_bytes()])
}
```