# How to return a struct with a reference to self in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've [implemented](https://github.com/l0b0/cronlist/tree/5c0ec9c63580a8ee9c18307964c2153cdb25d1b0) a `struct` which has a list of crontab entries, each of which knows its own recurrence (such as `*/5 * * * *` in crontab):

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::NaiveDateTime;

pub struct Crontab<'a> {
    entries: Vec<Entry<'a>>,
}

pub struct Entry<'a> {
    pub recurrence: Recurrence,
    pub command: &'a str,
}

pub struct Recurrence {
    minutes: Vec<u8>,
    hours: Vec<u8>,
    days_of_month: Vec<u8>,
    months: Vec<u8>,
    days_of_week: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Based on the current time you can get the next occurrence of a command:

```
impl Recurrence {
    pub fn next_match(&self, after: NaiveDateTime) -> NaiveDateTime {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a function on `Crontab` to get the `Entry` which will run next (that is, for which `recurrence.next_match()` is the lowest).

```
impl<'a> Crontab<'a> {
    fn next_run(&self, from: NaiveDateTime) -> Run<'a> {
        &self.entries
            .into_iter()
            .map(|entry| Run {
                entry: &entry,
                datetime: entry.recurrence.next_match(from),
            })
            .min_by(|this, other| this.datetime.cmp(&other.datetime))
            .unwrap()
    }
}

struct Run<'a> {
    entry: &'a Entry<'a>,
    datetime: NaiveDateTime,
}
```

This generates the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:9
   |
29 |       fn next_run(&self, from: NaiveDateTime) -> Run<'a> {
   |                                                  ------- expected `Run<'a>` because of return type
30 | /         &self.entries
31 | |             .into_iter()
32 | |             .map(|entry| Run {
33 | |                 entry: &entry,
...  |
36 | |             .min_by(|this, other| this.datetime.cmp(&other.datetime))
37 | |             .unwrap()
   | |_____________________^ expected struct `Run`, found &Run<'_>
   |
   = note: expected type `Run<'a>`
              found type `&Run<'_>`
```

Similar variants I've tried fail to compile with messages such as "cannot move out of borrowed content" (if changing the return type to `&Run<'a>`) or that the `&entry` does not live long enough.

It seems to make most sense that the `Run` should have a reference to rather than a copy of the `Entry`, but I'm not sure how to juggle both the lifetimes and references to get to that point (and I don't know whether `'a` refers to the same lifetime in both structs). What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps you would read [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423) and then [edit] your question to explain how it's different?

Comment: I haven't tried to compile (please post your errors instead), but the thing that seems immediately wrong is `.into_iter()`. That call consumes the original value. If you want `entries` to exist after you iterate them, you want [iter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.21.0/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) instead to iterate over references.

Comment: @Shepmaster It's different at least in that I'm passing in a reference to the object I'd like the response to refer to, `&self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423), you cannot create a value in a function and return a reference to it. Nothing would own the result of your iterator chain, thus the reference would point at invalid data.

That doesn't even really matter: as pointed out in the comments, you cannot call `into_iter` on `self.entries` because you cannot move out of borrowed content to start with, as described in [Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423). This means that we cannot have an owned value of an `Entry` as the result of the iterator chain to start with.

`Crontab` owns the `Entry`; as soon as the `Crontab` moves, any reference to any `Entry` becomes invalid. This means that any references need to be tied to how long `self` lives; the generic lifetime `'a` cannot come into play:

```
fn next_run(&self, from: NaiveDateTime) -> Run {
    self.entries
        .iter()
        .map(|entry| Run {
            entry,
            datetime: entry.recurrence.next_match(from),
        })
        .min_by(|this, other| this.datetime.cmp(&other.datetime))
        .unwrap()
}
```

Or the explicit version:

```
fn next_run<'b>(&'b self, from: NaiveDateTime) -> Run<'b> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Awesome! The error about moving out of borrowed content pointed to the `self.entries` line, so I thought it was unrelated to the `into_iter` call.