# How to implement prepend for a linked list without needing to assign to a new variable?

Tags: data-structures, rust, move-semantics, borrowing

Something told me how to implement a linked list:

```
enum List {
    Cons(u32, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}

impl List {
    fn prepend(self, elem: u32) -> List {
        Cons(elem, Box::new(self))
    }
}
```

When I want to use `prepend`, I need to do the following:

```
list = list.prepend(1);
```

However, I want to create a function that does not need to create a new variable every time `prepend` returns. I just want to change the `list` variable itself using `prepend`:

```
list.prepend(1);
```

Here is one implementation that I come up with, but it's not right:

```
fn my_prepend(&mut self, elem: u32) {
    *self = Cons(elem, Box::new(*self));
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158738/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content)

Comment: Note that a linked list is a chain of nodes, and usually a wrapper referencing the first node. Here, the `List` enumeration only represents a single node, so if you want to have a mutable list, you need a wrapper referencing the chain of `List`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List::prepend` *must* move `self` because that is literally what is happening. The new head of the list is a new object and the old head is moved onto the heap, making the old variable invalid.

Inside `my_prepend` you have a mutable reference to `self`, but then you move its value so that the `self` reference becomes invalid. Even though it's only invalid temporarily, this is what the message `"cannot move out of borrowed content"` is complaining about.

One way to get around this is to move `self` out into a variable and *simultaneously* replace it with `Nil`, so that the `self` reference is never invalid. You can do that with `mem::replace`:

```
use std::mem;

fn my_prepend(&mut self, elem: u32) {
    // Move the value of self into head, and leave self as Nil so it isn't invalid
    let head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);
    // Reassign to self with the prepended value
    *self = head.prepend(elem);
}
```