# What does it mean to "move out"?

Tags: rust

I got the following error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `piece.source` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/buffer.rs:77:37
   |
77 | ...                   source: piece.source,
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `piece.source` has type `buffer::PieceSource`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `piece.source` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/buffer.rs:84:37
   |
84 | ...                   source: piece.source,
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `piece.source` has type `buffer::PieceSource`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

and I don't understand what the compiler means by "move out".

Comment: How I read it, `move out of` means `move from`.

Comment: @rodrigo I mean in terms of semantics in the program.

Comment: @trentcl Does it? Does "move out" mean the same as "move"?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158738/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-cannot-move-out-of-behind-a-shared-referen

Comment: @Pablo If you stand up *out of your chair*, are you still standing up? Or is it not standing up, but *standing up out*?

Comment: @trentcl Is this a riddle?

Comment: @trentcl My answer is: I don't know

Comment: Ok, sorry, maybe that was a flippant response: I'm just trying to understand the confusion between "move" and "move out". To me, if you understand *move semantics*, which the linked question answers, I don't think there is any ambiguity about what the error message says, so I don't understand what there is to be confused about. Moving is inherently directional; there's a *from* and a *to* -- not only in Rust, but in English in general... "out of `piece.source`" is just a prepositional phrase that describes the *from* part.

Comment: @trentcl Ok, thanks. My first reaction was that the out meant a different thing, or else it would just say move. I don't picture an "inside" or an "outside" of an assignment.

Comment: @PabloTatoRamos Those terms begin to make sense when the assignment implements move. To make an analogy with the real world: if you take a page out of a book, the book will no longer be complete. And if the book doesn't belong to you (it's borrowed), you're not allowed to leave it in an invalid state.