# How to implement `take_until` to borrow an immutable reference then I can call another method

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm making a parser:

```rust
pub enum TokenContent {
    Breaks,
    Heading(usize),
    CodeFence(usize),
    Text,
    NewLine(NewLineType),
}

pub struct Token {
    pub content: TokenContent,
    pub range: Range<usize>,
}

pub struct Parser<'raw> {
    stream: TokenStream<'raw>,
}
```

`token_stream` is a data structure that can provide a sequence of tokens from the lexer:

```rust
pub struct TokenStream<'raw> {
    raw: &'raw str,                    // track the str to parse
    source: Peekable<TokenIter<'raw>>, // iterator of token
}
```

I want to implement a method on `TokenStream` named `take_until` to return a new `Iterator` from the current position of `TokenStream.source` to the specific `stop` symbol:

```rust
impl<'raw> TokenStream<'raw> {
    pub fn take_until(&self, stop: TokenContent) -> impl Iterator<Item = Token> + 'raw {
        self.source.peek_while(move |x| x.content != stop)
    }
}
```

Meet the error:

```
cannot move out of `self.source` which is behind a mutable reference
move occurs because `self.source` has type `Peekable<LexerIntoIterator<'_>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` traitrustcE0507
```

How to implement `take_until` borrow the immutable reference of `TokenStream` then I can call another method on `TokenStream` after I call `take_until`? Is there some Rust-native way to do it?

My peek_while.rs:

```rust
use std::{
    iter::Peekable
};

pub struct PeekWhile<I: Iterator, P> {
    iter: Peekable<I>,
    predicate: P,
}

impl<I: Iterator, P> PeekWhile<I, P> {
    pub fn new(iter: I, predicate: P) -> Self {
        Self {
            iter: iter.peekable(),
            predicate,
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator, P> Iterator for PeekWhile<I, P>
where
    P: FnMut(&I::Item) -> bool,
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let x = self.iter.peek()?;
        if (self.predicate)(&x) {
            Some(self.iter.next().unwrap())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

pub trait PeekWhileExt: Iterator {
    fn peek_while<P>(self, predicate: P) -> PeekWhile<Self, P>
    where
        P: FnMut(&<Self as Iterator>::Item) -> bool,
        Self: Sized,
    {
        PeekWhile::new(self, predicate)
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> PeekWhileExt for I {}
```

Comment: In `TokenStream` you have `source` as `Peekable`, but `Peekable` does not implement `peek_while`. I guess it should be the `PeekWhile` type you provide?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/11328568)? My guess is that it will be the same problem since you have implemented: `fn peek_while<P>(self, predicate: P)` instead of `fn peek_while<P>(&self, predicate: P)`  (note the reference before `self`)

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: Notably, `NewLineType`, `Range` and `TokenIter` are not defined. We don't know if you created these or imported them (and if so, from what crate(s) and their versions).

Answer (score -1):

This consumes `self`:

```rust
pub trait PeekWhileExt: Iterator {
    fn peek_while<P>(self, predicate: P) -> PeekWhile<Self, P>
    where
        P: FnMut(&<Self as Iterator>::Item) -> bool,
        Self: Sized,
    {
        PeekWhile::new(self, predicate)
    }
}
```

Taking the reference of `self` should solve the problem:

```rust
fn peek_while<P>(&self, predicate: P)
...
```

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158738/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-cannot-move-out-of-behind-a-shared-referen)