# Cannot move out of `config.filename` which is behind a shared reference. I don't know why I got this error

Tags: rust, ownership

I have this function

```
pub struct Config {
    pub query: String,
    pub filename: String,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new(args: &Vec<String>) -> Result<Config, &str> {
        if args.len() > 3 {
            return Err("Error");
        }

        let query = args[1].clone();
        let filename = args[2].clone();
        Ok(Config {query, filename})
    }
}

pub fn run(config: &Config) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)?;
    for i in search(&config.query, &contents) {
        println!("Found: {}", i);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I got an error "cannot move out of `config.filename` which is behind a shared reference" when run this

```
if let Err(e) = run(&config) {
    println!("Error:{}", e);
    process::exit(1);
}

run(&config);
```

I really don't know why I got this error. Can anyone please explain it? Many thanks.

Comment: Try `fs::read_to_string(&config.filename)`

Comment: Can you please explain why this error happen? I don't understand. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot move out of borrowed content / cannot move out of behind a shared reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158738/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-cannot-move-out-of-behind-a-shared-referen)

Comment: It would be helpful to those trying to answer your question if you would include the full output of `cargo build`. This would include the error message as well as point to the particular line of code where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `read_to_string(config.filename)`, you're *moving* `filename` (i.e. transferring ownership) into `read_to_string`. But you don't *have* ownership since `run` only borrows `config`.

Since [`read_to_string` actually takes `AsRef<Path>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html) (i.e. anything that can be referenced as a `Path`), it can work with a borrowed string as well as an owned one. So you can solve the issue by simply *lending* `filename`: `read_to_string (&config.filename)`.